# New to Java, trying to create a program "Old Macdonald"

Tags: java, methods, input, output

Hey everyone my name is Abraham Esparza and I am currently teaching myself JAVA. Currently I am trying to create a program that asks feedback from the user. I saw several examples of an “Old Mac Donald” program and I wanted to modify it so that it contains a custom method and prompts the user for feedback. I want the program to start with "Old Macdonald had a farm" and prompt the user to input "please enter EIEIO" if the user enter anything else other than "EIEIO" the program will ask them to try again. If the user types "EIEIO" the program moves to the rest of the song. 
Please help.

here is what I have so far

```
    package pkgnew.newthod;
    import java.lang.String;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class NewNewthod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("Old MacDonald Had a Farm");
        System.out.println( );

        // print first verse with a method call
        int EIEIO, User, message;
        // print second and third verses (not done yet)
    }

    // This method prints the Old Macdonald line
    public void User( ) {
        System.out.println("Old Macdonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(EIEIO(message));
    }

    public String EIEIO(String message){
        System.out.printf("please enter EIEIO");      
        if (message.equals("E-I-E-I-O"))
        return "please enter EIEIO";
        return EIEIO(String (message));}
        else // after the the user types EIEIO i want the program to proceed the next section, but i get illegal start of type
        {
            System.out.println("With a moo-moo here and a moo-moo there");          
            System.out.println("And on his farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O");
            System.out.println("Here a moo there a moo");
            System.out.println("Everywhere a moo-moo");
            System.out.println( );{}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you're part way there.  You've described the desired behavior, but you haven't told us a specific problem or error that you are getting.  Simply posting all your code and expecting other people to get it to run and debug it for you is less likely to garner good responses than if you take the time to give a complete explanation of your problem.

Comment: you are right, i am sorry for my short description. so the first hurdle is the "else" statement i can't get it to work. I want my program do move to the next sequence of the song after the user types "EIEIO" as of now i get "illegal start of type"

Comment: I tried to reformat your code to improve readability, but the curly brackets don't match up.

Comment: Ok so i clean the code as much i could using Netbeans... thank you for the feedback.

Comment: This code won't even compile: missing brackets, two consecutive return statements etc. My advice: take a baby steps, start by doing one thing at the time and after each step run your program to make sure it works and only then continue.

Comment: thank you for the advice but i have spent several days trying to crack this problem. I bought "Sams Teach yourself JAVA" along with "murach's Java programing 4th edition". i have also watch more yourtube videos, and taken notes every time i find something new. I know i have a long way but i want to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code quite messy and I can only offer advice but not an answer.

Re: Good Practice:

- Use camelcase.
- INDENT YOUR CODE.
- Be as specific as you can regarding what your problem is.
- Just solve little bits of your problem at a time. I see no reason to use Scanner() or overcomplicate things. Just keep it simple.
- Always remember KISS and WIMP. (KISS is Keep It Simple Stupid) (WIMP is What Is My Problem) WIMP is my own invention for problem solving. ;D

Re: Your Code:

- Your methods need to be static as they are in the same file as your main().
- To call a method, just use the method name with parentheses, eg `user();`.

=====

"I'm currently trying to sort out your code and thought I'd whip this up quickly for your benefit. (It's your idea re-written my way)."

Hope this helps for now.

```
package oldMcDonald;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyAttempt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        callFirstLine();
        callEiEiO();
        System.out.println("And on his farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O,");
        System.out.println("With a moo-moo here and a moo-moo there");
        System.out.println("Here a moo, there a moo,");
        System.out.println("Everywhere a moo-moo.");
        callFirstLine();
        callEiEiO();
    }
    public static void callFirstLine(){
        System.out.println("Old McDonald had a farm,");
    }
    public static void callEiEiO() {
        String input = "";
        do{
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter 'EiEiO': ");
        }while (!"EiEiO".equals(input));
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am dumbfounded by how fast you got this running. I am going to be studding this for a while.

Comment: Pure practice.
If you need any help or want any info on the above code. Just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Harmelodic is incorrect and unfortunately teaching you bad practices.

A method does not have to be static in order to be called in the same class as your main, further to this NEVER EVER do work in your main method, it is horrifically bad practice, not doing work in your main resolves the issue of having to have all static methods.

```
package oldMcDonald;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyAttempt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAttempt matt = new MyAttempt();
        matt.run();
    }
    public void run(){
        callFirstLine();
        callEiEiO();
        System.out.println("And on his farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O,");
        System.out.println("With a moo-moo here and a moo-moo there");
        System.out.println("Here a moo, there a moo,");
        System.out.println("Everywhere a moo-moo.");
        callFirstLine();
        callEiEiO();
    }
    public svoid callFirstLine(){
        System.out.println("Old McDonald had a farm,");
    }
    public void callEiEiO() {
        String input = "";
        do{
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter 'EiEiO': ");
        }while (!"EiEiO".equals(input));
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i wan not aware of proper practices. is there any books you might recommend that will teach me proper habits?

thank you kindly.